# How to capture local and remote shell variables in shell script

Tags: shell

I am trying to execute a command on remote host using ssh. Here I need to capture exit code of that remote command on that remote host and at the same time I need to capture exit code of my ssh command. How can I capture both the local and remote shell variables from same command?

Basically the requirement is:

```
ssh user@remotehost "/etc/stop_database; echo $?"
```

Based on the return code of my ssh command I need to perform some actions.

```
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
echo ssh failed
else
echo ssh success
fi
```

Also based on the exit code of remote command in that host, I need to perform below actions:

```
if database_stopped; then
echo DB stopped successfully
else
echo Unable to stop DB
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Provided that stop_database doesn't produce any output or gets redirected, the remote `echo $?` could be captured to a script var plus access the ssh exit code; in this simulation example, `"ssh yadda ..."` is replaced with local stuff:

```
#!/bin/bash

rmt_sd=$(echo 23; exit 46)
ssh_ec=$?

echo rmt_sd $rmt_sd, ssh_ec $ssh_ec
```